# iOS DJI SDK doesn't play 60 fps 1080p video from Phantom 4 Advanced/Pro and hangs

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

DJI SDK version is latest 4.8.1. iOS version is latest. We try to play 1080p video with 60/30 fps. Color mode is the default.

```
- (void)playVideo:(DJIMediaFile *)videoMedia withCompletion:(DJICompletionBlock)completion;
```

Executes fine(no errors)

```
-(void)manager:(DJIMediaManager *)manager didUpdateVideoPlaybackState:(DJIMediaVideoPlaybackState* )state
```

Executes fine (Playing)

```
-(void)manager:(DJIMediaManager *)manager didUpdateVideoPlaybackData:(uint8_t* )data length:(size_t)length forRendering:(BOOL)forRendering

-(void)videoFeed:(DJIVideoFeed *)videoFeed didUpdateVideoData:(NSData* )videoData
```

These delegates do not receive any bit of data and therefore SDK becomes unresponsive and doesn't work until we restart app. Please help

Comment: This issue is always reproduced?, We already try reproduce it, but failed.

Comment: yep, right now since you deprecated PlaybackManager, MediaManager started to play everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, DJI finally deprecates PlaybackManager and MediaManager is only way to play files. 
That is why and due to our tests we see that video plays fine now on old devices.